# Inheritance doubts

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm relatively new to OOP, so wanted to clear a few things,

I have the following piece of code

```
class Parent
{
     public Parent()
     {
           Console.WriteLine("Parent Class constructor");
     }

     public void Print()
     {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent->Print()");
     }
}

class Child : Parent
{
     public Child() 
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Child class constructor");
     }

     public static void Main()
     {
           Child ChildObject = new Child();
           Parent ParentObject = new Child();

           ChildObject.Print();
           ParentObject.Print();
     }

}
```

Output :

```
Parent Class Constructor
Child Class constructor

Parent Class Constructor
Child Class constructor

Parent->Print()
Parent->Print()
```

My questions are as follows :

1) Why is the base class constructor called when I instantiate objects with the `ChildClass` constructor? without explicitly specifying the `base` keyword. Is there any way to **avoid** calling the base class constructor?

2) why is `ParentClass ParentObj = new ChildClass();` possible? and not the other way round.

Comment: I assume you mean for Child to inherit from Parent.

Comment: There are tons of basic errors in your code, this doesn't even compile. Please post real code, not pseudo code. (`main` should be `Main`, `ParentObj` should be `ParentObject`, you're missing `System.`...)

Comment: Sidenote (sorry for being pedantic): The terminology of your code, `Parent`/`Child`, is slightly misleading. Do you agree that inheritance in OOP, ie. deriving a type from another, can be thought of as modelling an "is-a" relationship? Why then "is" a `Child` a `Parent`? That's not a very fitting analogy to the real world. `Parent` vs. `Child` is somewhat reminiscent of a master-detail relationship, but not of proper type inheritance. `Base`/`Derived` or `Superclass`/`Subclass` would've sounded more appropriate.

Comment: @Kerrek hey sorry about those errors, wrote it pretty quickly so missed those, have edited my post ! thanks.

Comment: @stakx hey, I generally refer to them as parent class and child class, but as you said, if you keep an `is-a` relationship in mind, it doesn't seem right, thanks for the comment will keep that in mind !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

By `Child` inheriting `Parent`, the child object takes on the characteristics of the parent. If you think of it in genetic terms, it may make more sense.

> 1) Why is the base class constructor called when I instantiate objects
>   with the ChildClass constructor? without explicitly specifying the
>   base keyword. Is there any way to avoid calling the base class
>   constructor?

There is no way to get around the base class constructor being called (that I am aware of). The point of having the base class constructor called is to instantiate the base class (pass parameters, initialize other objects, assign values, etc.)

> 2) why is ParentClass ParentObj = new ChildClass(); possible? and not
>   the other way round.

Because of polymorhism, `Child` **looks** like `Parent` and therefore may be instantiated as `Parent`. Since Parent does not inherit Child, Parent does not look like Child and therefore may not be instantiated as `Child`.

For what it's worth, using Parent and Child have different meanings. Typically, when referring to inheritance, `Parent` is the base class, where `Child` would be the *derived* or *sub-type*.

Answer (score 6):

1. All base class constructors all the way up inheritance tree will get called. Constructors are always chained starting with the parent class on down to the most derived class.
2. Instances of `ChildClass` "are" instances of `ParentClass`. They model an "is-a" relationship, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

1. Because the compilator inserts `: base()` if you don't specify otherwise.
   You can explicitly call `: base("foo")` if you have a constructor `Parent(string s)`, then `Parent()` is not called. You can not skip the base class constructor calling all together.
2. Because `Animal animal = new Dog();` makes sense and not `Dog dog = new Animal();` A dog is always an animal, but not necessarily the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

1) Probably confusing because you are using Child/Parent nomenclature.  Because Child/Parent implies two different instances (an owner relationship).  Inheritance is an Is-A relationship.  A dog is an animal.  So a dog class could inherit from animal.

2) Again, you can have an animal which happens to be a dog, but you only have an animal handle on it.  Like you could be holding a leash and it could have an elephant or a flea on the other end, but a leash can hold any animal.

Answer (score 0):

1) There are (or could be) private members in the base class which the child class knows nothing about, but are necessary. Hence the parent constructor is called first to cover this eventuality.

2) `ChildClass` is a type of `ParentClass` as `Square` is a type of `Rectangle`. That's the theory, anyway. That's why it doesn't make sense to have it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

1)  In C#, if you don't specify a call to a *different* constructor using something like `base(blah)`, it will call the *default* constructor.  Which you've defined above.

2)  Every `ChildClass` will always be a `ParentClass`.  However, there may be objects that are a `ParentClass` but are not a `ChildClass`.  For example, if you had an `OtherChildClass : ParentClass`, it would be a `ParentClass`, but it would not be a `ChildClass`.

Comment: You *can* specify the base default constructor although not common. Not a bad practice - some people do, some people don't.